# How do I make my cellphone app fill out the whole screen in a tablet (Xoom)?

Tags: android, android-layout, tablet, xoom

I tried to run my application into the Xoom tablet and it ended up being of the exactly same size of a cellphone (it doesn't fill out the entire screen).

So, I created a very simply project which just shows a degrade image and a progress bar in the middle. I had the same result, as you can see it in the picture below:

[Xoom - Tiny screen http://raphaeu.com/gvt/Imagem.jpg](http://raphaeu.com/gvt/Imagem.jpg)

So, how would I go on writing my layout in order to fill out the entire screen of the tablet?

Here is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

Here is my main.xml layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:background="@drawable/splash_portrait">

<ProgressBar 
    style="?android:progressBarStyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is the entire project, if you want to take a look at it: 
http://raphaeu.com/gvt/xoom.zip

Thank you very much in advance!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this to your manifest..

```
<supports-screens
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:anyDensity="false" />
```

Here is details ...
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution.html

Answer (score 0):

Try adjusting your xml layout to use "fill_parent" for height and width. Using wrap_content tells the view to only take up as much space as needed, rather than growing to fit the available screen size.

Comment: If you look at his actual source he has a relative layout as the root layout set to fill_parent.